# Passar dados de uma tabela HTML para o controller ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, tabela-html

Estou tentando passar os dados de uma tabela HTML em minha view para meu Controller.
Os dados nessa tabela sao adicionados dinamicamente. Abre-se um BootStrap Modal, onde o usuario informa alguns dados, quando clicado o botao `Ok`, os dados sao adicionado a tabela via JavaScript.
Ate ai, tudo funcionando.
Depois de todos os dados informados, preciso passar estes para meu controller para inseri-los no meu BD. 
Ai esta o problema!
Ja tentei de muitas maneiras, mas ainda nao consegui nada.
Este e o codigo da minha View que contem minha tabela:

```
@model prjArqBuild.entidade_endereco
<div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#endereco">
                    Endereços
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="endereco" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table class="table" id="tabEndereco">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                Endereco
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Numero
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Complemento
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Bairro
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Cidade
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                UF
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                CEP
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
                <p class="panel-title">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalEndereco">
                        Adicionar Endereço
                    </button>

                    <!-- Modal -->
                    <div class="modal fade" id="ModalEndereco" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Cadastro de Endereço</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <fieldset id="infoEndereco">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.een_endereco, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-sm", placeholder = "Endereço" } })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.een_endereco, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.een_numero, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-sm", placeholder = "Numero" } })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.een_numero, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <br />
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.een_comple, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-sm", placeholder = "Complemento" } })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.een_comple, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <br />
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.een_bairro, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-sm", placeholder = "Bairro" } })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.een_bairro, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.een_cidade, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-sm", placeholder = "Cidade" } })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.een_cidade, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <br />
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.een_uf, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-sm", placeholder = "Estado" } })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.een_uf, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.een_cep, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-sm", placeholder = "CEP" } })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.een_cep, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </fieldset>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                                    <button id="addEndereco" type="button" OnClick="gravarDetalheEnd();" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Esta e' minha funcao JavaScript que coloca os dados na tabela dinamicamente:

```
function gravarDetalheEnd() {
            $('#tabEndereco tr:last').after('<tr><td>' + $('#een_endereco').val() + '</td><td>' + $('#een_numero').val() + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + $('#een_comple').val() + '</td>' + '<td>' + $('#een_bairro').val() + '</td>'
                + '<td>' + $('#een_cidade').val() + '</td>' + '<td>' + $('#een_uf').val() + '</td>'
                + '<td>' + $('#een_cep').val() + '</td></tr>');
        }
```

Este e' meu metodo no Controller onde preciso receber os dados:

```
 public void AddEndereco(entidade_endereco entEnd)
        {
            db.entidade_endereco.Add(entEnd);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

**Note que preciso recebe-los como `entidade_endereco`**

Ja tentei utilizar varias funcoes e 'AJAX' para passa-lo ao Controller, mas sem nenhuma resposta. 
**Alguem tem alguma ideia?**

Comment: Você deseja enviar utilizando Ajax ou uma requisição `POST` convencional?

Answer (score 3):

Posso ser ainda um jovem [padawan](http://www.significados.com.br/padawan/), mas sem dúvidas eu usaria [Json](http://www.json.org/json-pt.html).

Bem, primeiro você precisa reestruturar de forma rápida sua tabela, acrescentando uma classe por exemplo, para poder obter seus dados de maneira mais fácil.

> ***ATENÇÃO***: Pode-se questionar aqui sobre qual seria a melhor forma de estruturar sua tabela para obter os dados, mas este não é o foco da
>   pergunta e sim o envio de tais dados da `View` para o `Controller`.

Veja um exemplo de como ficaria a tabela já com alguns dados inseridos pelo usuário:

```html
<table id="tabEndereco" border="1">
  <tr class="cabecalho">
    <th>Endereco</th>
    <th>Numero</th>
    <th>Complemento</th>
    <th>Bairro</th>
    <th>Cidade</th>
    <th>UF</th>
    <th>CEP</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="item">
    <td>Rua dos bobos</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>Casa engraçada</td>
    <td>Bairro do esmero</td>
    <td>Stacklândia</td>
    <td>SOpt</td>
    <td>0123-456</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="item">
    <td>Rua dos sábios</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>Casa sem graça</td>
    <td>Bairro sem esmero</td>
    <td>Overflowlândia</td>
    <td>SOen</td>
    <td>6543-210</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Para obter esse resultado, basta alterar sua função `gravarDetalheEnd()` acrescentando uma `class` na `tr`.

Agora vamos para a melhor parte! Ao clicar em um botão para enviar os dados para o `Controller` (vamos chama-lo de `btn-enviar`) a seguinte função deverá ser executada:

```
$("#btn-enviar").click(function(){
  var todos_enderecos = [];

  // Varrendo todos os itens inseridos (olha a vassoura!)
  $('.item').each(function() {

    // Montando objeto que possui as mesmas propriedades do objeto C# do Controller.
    var entidade_endereco = {
      endereco : $(this).children()[0].innerText,
      numero : $(this).children()[1].innerText,
      complemento: $(this).children()[2].innerText,
      bairro : $(this).children()[3].innerText,
      cidade: $(this).children()[4].innerText,
      uf : $(this).children()[5].innerText,
      cep : $(this).children()[6].innerText
    };

    // Adicionando objeto a lista.
    todos_enderecos.push(entidade_endereco);
  });

  // Após validações, chame a função que possui o Ajax para enviar a lista obtida.
  enviarDados(todos_enderecos);
});
```

Sua função `enviarDados` ficaria semelhante a essa:

```
function enviarDados(todos_enderecos){
   $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: '@Url.Action("Action","Controller")',
      data: JSON.stringify(todos_enderecos)
   });
}
```

Mais sobre [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

E em seu `Controller` basta criar um método para receber um `List<entidade_endereco>`.